# Check for filenames with version fields larger than those of a given filename

Tags: java, comparison

I have a file of the following format `update_0_9_26`. I want to write java code which will check for all files having a version greater than `0_9_26` . For example `0_9_27` and so on. I have to perform processing on the files which are retrieved from this calculation.

**How should I parse the filename in order to retrieve those greater than the referece name?**

Example input:

```
update_0_9_26.sql 
update_0_9_27.sql 
update_0_9_28.sql 
update_1_0_0.sql
update_1_0_1.sql
update_1_0_2.sql
```

Expected output (when searching for "larger than `update_0_9_26`"):

```
update_0_9_27.sql 
update_0_9_28.sql
```

Comment: I do not see any question there.

Comment: Edited to try to make the question stand out more. Please comment if over-edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple step-by-step guide:

1. Get the file-names from the filesystem, using `new File("myDirName").list()`
2. Sort that list into a TreeSet created using a custom comparator (see below).
3. Iterate through the set, processing your files in order, but not including the ones you have already seen. Use `myTreeSet.tailSet(lastFileToNotProcess, 'true')` to get a view of the set that contains only those elements.

The fun part is in step 2. Here is a custom comparator that tokenizes its input and compares integer tokens numerically, and non-integer tokens alphabetically:

```
class TokenizingComparator implements Comparator<String> {
   private String separator;
   private static Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
   public TokenizingComparator(String separator) { this.separator = separator; }
   public int compare(String a, String b) {
      String pa[] = a.split(separator);
      String pb[] = b.split(separator);
      for (int ia=0, ib=0; ia<pa.length && ib<pb.length; ia++,ib++) {
          int rc = comparePart(pa[ia], pb[ib]);
          if (rc != 0) return rc;
      } 
      return (pa.length != pb.length) ? 
         pa.length - pb.length : 0;
   }
   private comparePart(String a, String b) {
      if (intPattern.matcher(a).matches() && intPattern.matcher(b).matches()) {
         return Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(b);
      } else {
         return a.compareTo(b);
      }
   }
}
```